# confluent hypergeometric equation

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I just proved that by writing $w(z)$ in the form of an integral equation the hypergeometric equation $zw''+(c-w)w'-aw=0$ has solutions in the form $\int_\gamma t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}e^{tz}dt$ providing that $t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}e^{tz} |_\gamma=0$

My question now is that in the case $Re z>0$ I want to find paths which provide two independent solutions in the cases ($m$ is a pos. integer)

(i): $a=-m,c=0$

(ii): $Re a<0, c=0$ $a$ not an integer

Can you help me with that?